# Searching for a string, then clicking the parent DIV with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I am working on some test automation for a RIA I have written, and I am having some trouble when attempting to search for a given string within the DOM, then clicking on the DIV that encapsulates said string. I am using selenium with cucumber.

The structure of my tests look like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── containers
│   │   ├── AddCustomerContainer.java
│   │   ├── HomePageContainer.java
│   │   ├── LoginErrorPageContainer.java
│   │   └── LoginPageContainer.java
│   ├── NaviagtorFactory.java
│   ├── Navigation.java
│   ├── User.java
│   ├── Users.java
│   └── view
│       ├── AddCustomerView.java
│       ├── HomeView.java
│       ├── LoginErrorView.java
│       └── LoginView.java
├── constants
│   ├── Browsers.java
│   ├── CredentialsType.java
│   └── Outcome.java
└── utils
    ├── BrowserDriver.java
    ├── BrowserFactory.java
    └── FileUtils.java
```

the tests are run from `Navigation.java`, this is how I am trying to search for a string then click on it's parent currently:

```
//Navigation.java    
public void given_I_navigate_to_the_add_customer_page(){
        BrowserDriver.loadPage("localhost:3000");
        AddCustomerView.clickAddCustomer();
    }
```

then in AddCustomerView.java:

```
private static final AddCustomerContainer addCustomerContainer = PageFactory.initElements(BrowserDriver.getCurrentDriver(), AddCustomerContainer.class);

public static void clickAddCustomer(){
    LOGGER.info("Navigating to Add Customer");
    addCustomerContainer.getAddCustomerButton().click();
}
```

AddCustomerContainer.java:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*")
    public WebElement all;

public WebElement getAddCustomerButton(){
    WebElement button = BrowserDriver.getText(all, "Add customer");
    return button;
}
```

And this is the getText function in the BrowserDriver.java

```
public static WebElement getText(WebElement element, String value) {
    return element.findElement(By.partialLinkText(value));
}
```

The text I am searching for is 'Add Customer' with the XPATH //* however when the tests run selenium just seemingly cannot find the string.

In respects of structure and driver set up, everything is OK, as I am running several other tests which function as expected. Finding a string is somewhat of an enigma, however.

I have tried several methods of getting the string:

```
return element.findElement(By.linkText("Add customer"));
return element.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Add customer"));
return element.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Add customer')]"));
```

None of which work... Any suggestions? Cheers!

Edit:
This is the HTML, it is worth mentioning that this appears in a frame however I used chrome to get the xpath and it was `//*[@id="login-success"]/p[1]/a[2]`:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
OATime
</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">

<style type="text/css"></style></head>

<body id="login-success" class="chooser">
<br>
<p align="center">
<strong>version_TOKEN</strong>
<br>
<br>
<a target="main" href="/customer-list" class="screenlink">List customers</a><br>
<a target="main" href="/customer-edit" class="screenlink">Add customer</a><br>
<br>
<a target="_top" href="/logout" class="screenlink">Sign out</a>
</p>
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: I've never seen this. You are using page factory to find an element called `all` using the XPath expression `//*`. This will return a list of web elements, but you're storing only 1 single WebElement instance, which is probably the first one found in the document, usually `<html>`. Is this the usual way in cucumber? Looks a little strange to me.

Comment: admittedly I have been following the convention of using @FindBy with a specific ID, this is the first time I have done it this way I assumed this was the way to search the entire DOM for text

Comment: I have updated the question with the HTML

Comment: @KimHomann @florent-b I have changed the findby from `//*` to the xpath given by chrome for the element `//*[@id='login-success']/p[1]/a[2]` this still hasn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With selenium you need to set the context on the frame where the targeted element is. So in your case it should be something like this:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*")
public WebElement all;

public WebElement getAddCustomerButton(){
    BrowserDriver.switchTo().frame(0);
    WebElement button = BrowserDriver.getText(all, "Add customer");
    return button;
}
```

And to set back the default context once you're done with the frame:

```
    BrowserDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: getting: `/autotest/src/main/java/com/autotest/app/containers/AddCustomerContainer.java:[18,15] error: cannot find symbol` when I use switchTo() on `BrowserDriver.switchTo().frame(0);`

Comment: Since it's a customised implementation, it could be something like  BrowserDriver.Instance.switchTo().frame(0);

Comment: You need to find the instance of the web driver or the switch method in BrowserDriver to make it work. The BrowserDriver class is not a part of the Selenium framework.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your help, went into zombie mode there for a bit. Found the instance for the WebDriver, switched the frame, worked.